# Adding an Extension Method to a Generic class

Tags: c#, generics, abstract-class, extension-methods

How can i create a extension of my Container class? without testing the DB Type.

```
public abstract class DBAccess : IDBAccess, IDisposable
{
}

public class DB1 : DBAccess
{
}

public class DB2 : DBAccess
{
}

public partial class TAContainer<T> : TableAdapterModel<T, DTContainer>, ITAContainer
    where T : DBAccess, new()
{
}
```

Now my extension would like something

```
public static int ExecuteByExtension(this ITAContainer tAContainer, IDTContainer dataTable)
{
    var ta = (tAContainer as TableAdapter<DB1>);


}
```

This all works. But i would like to set the variable ta to the abstract class "DBAccess". This cannot be done, also using a interface is not possible.

How to use a single Type for the casting. and not testing for DB1 or DB2

the result should be called like:

```
var dataTable = new DTContainer() as IDTContainer;
var container = new TAContainer<DB1>() as ITAContainer;
int result = container.ExecuteByExtension(datatable);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in the ExecuteByExtension method? What is the definition of the TableAdapter type?

Comment: _"I would like to set the variable ta to the abstract class "DBAccess""_ - why? How? There is no inheritance chain from `ITAContainer` to `DBAccess` in any way. _If_ `ITAContainer` happens to be a `TableAdapter<DB1>`, then still, you can't just cast it to `DBAccess` or `DB1`, just as you can't cast a `List<string>` to a `string`.

Answer (score 2):

Could you just add the generic argument to your extension method, like this:

```
public static int ExecuteByExtension<T>(
     this TAContainer<T> tAContainer, IDTContainer dataTable) where T : DBAccess, new()
{
    var ta = (tAContainer as TableAdapter<T>);
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, almost. But i would like that the extension method can be called with: 

var container = new TAContainer<DB1>() as ITAContainer;

int result = container.ExecuteByExtension();

Comment: This is the way I would recommend as well. If you want to remove the implicit cast, you need to define TAContainer<T> to expose the methods TableAdapter<T> has and this extension method needs. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think that certain generic parameters can be inferred by visual studio.  you may be able to use the syntax you are showing.  meaning the compiler knows to carry forward the generic type used in the constructor for certain methods or extension methods.  I'll check and report back